# React Native VirtualizedList get Scroll and scroll to position

Tags: react-native

So i am on RN 49.3, 
I am looking for a way to get the scroll position or the index of the item visible on the virtualizedList!

PS: when i opened the source code of VirtualizedList.js which seems to have props.onScrollEndDrag & props.onScroll

Comment: You want to remember scroll position and then scroll to that position when you get back to the srceen?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what i am trying to do. 
it seems that my initial approche is not very efficient, because it will overload the bridge.
Right now i am trying to store the index of the element before leaving the screen and use scrollToIndex to scroll to back to the right position.
and yet i am facing a problem with the reference of the virtualizedList wich i loose when i leave the screen. 
If you have any insight in this, the help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were using a different approach. It has changed a lot since, but I can help you with the initial approach. We added `onScroll` param to the list. We captured `event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y` into the state or some variable inside spec. We used redux. When the user left the screen we saved this value inside a database. Second part was to load this value from the db in `componentDidMount` . You just put a `ref` into the list component and then call `this.refs.myRef.scrollTo({ x: 0, y: loadedValue, animated: false });`

Capture the scroll

```
    render() {
      return (
        <VirtualizedList 
            ref='myRef'
            onScroll={event => {
                this.scroll = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
            }}
            ...
        />
    );}
```

Save on exit

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    AsyncStorage.setItem(key, this.scroll);
}
```

Load after mounting

```
componentDidMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem(key)
        .then(y => {
            this.refs.myRef.scrollTo({ x: 0, y, animated: false });
        });
}
```

Best approach I think is to handle it inside redux and you connect this component with the list to the store. I mentioned saving into db because we do save the position for later use, this is only optional and depends on your requirements.
You may use the state as well, but then you need to handle the unnecessary updates

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
Actually, in the end, i used a similar approach, by setting the index of the element I want to scroll to in the state and using the scrollToIndex method. which worked perfectly!